# Python put the output in a new file

Tags: python, string, file, proxy, integer

I'm trying to put this output in a new file

```
{   "origin": "91.233.25.148" }
```

this is my code

```
import os

def proxy():
    for i in range(10000):
        f = open('proxy.txt', 'a')
        a = os.system('curl -x "http://scraperapi:eabc06bd706c776cf4d8794f61288c31@proxy-server.scraperapi.com:8001"
-k "http://httpbin.org/ip"')
        print(f'{a}',file=f)

proxy()
```

but in proxy.txt I got only this

```
0
```

how can I put the output in a proxy.txt file

Comment: Read the documentatiion of [`os.system`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system). The return value is the exit status of the process. Use the appropriate functions from the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module.

Comment: every time a file is open and not closed a kitten dies.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that os.system only return the error code from your command (0 means everything is ok). But you can get the content directly from the curl command with -o proxy.txt (not tested).